# How can I delete rows containing nonsense characters in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to be able to remove all rows containing nonsense characters such as the ones shown below in a pandas dataframe.

[image]

I have tried this code to delete rows containing gibberish data like this:

```py
def dropgibbris(df):
    df = df.astype(str)
    dropList=[]
    for i in range(len(df)):
        col1=df.iloc[i, 0]
        col2=df.iloc[i, 1]
        col3=df.iloc[i, 2]
        if col1.isalnum() and col2.isalnum() and col3.isalnum():
            pass
        else:
            dropList.append(df.iloc[i].name)
    for i in dropList:
        df.drop(index=i,inplace=True)
    return df
```

it's not working because isalnum() function is saying these values `77.594667`,`2023-04-24T10:44:20.4912482+00:00`,`EKO_18006_26/11/20` are also not alpnum so it's deleting the entire dataframe.I think regx might help?

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of the data?

Comment: no it's not working because `isalnum()` function is saying there values `77.594667`,`2023-04-24T10:44:20.4912482+00:00`,`EKO_18006_26/11/20` are also not alpnum so it's deleting the entire dataframe.I think regx might help what do you think? @mozway

Answer (score 0):

I assume something like this would work

```
def dropgibbris(df, cols_to_check):
    df = df.astype(str).copy()
    df = df[df[cols_to_check].apply(
        lambda x: all(x[col].isalnum() for col in cols_to_check),
        axis=1,
    )]
    return df
df = dropgibbris(df, ["col_1", "col_2", "col_3"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `string.printable` to determine if each character is printable or not. Compute a ratio to choose if you want to drop the row or not:

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
import string

pat = '|'.join(re.escape(c) for c in string.printable)

ratio = df['Col1'].str.replace(pat, '', regex=True).str.len() / df['Col1'].str.len()
```

```
>>> df
          Col1
0   ¨P õEÙ$Î
1   /3Ô9
3   K0ZW\k:PV*
4   %qMzM%Aq%_
5  o[\-;C}jk\n
6  [3Sz\r;e#
7
7   }üx
Ö
8   ;f~_)a%),J
9   CoZ@nQKc(P

>>> ratio
0    0.7
1    0.4
2    0.6
3    0.0
4    0.0
5    0.0
6    0.0
7    0.8
8    0.0
9    0.0
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
```

Now you can filter out rows where the ratio is greater than a threshold.